# find the order or rank of a database entry relative to a field in a mysql database in rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table which connects my users to payments they have made and their values.

I need to be able to find the rank of a users payment. This is to say:

```
Find Users payment -> Order Payments by value descending -> Return row position of users payment.
```

Or:

```
User pays $10

There are three people who have paid more than $10

Return 4
```

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, if there's 10 payment records for example, the one for this particular user is number 2, you simply want to get that number 2 as a return value?

Comment: Precisely. I'll add that example.

Comment: If user A has made payments of $20 and $15 and user B has made payment of $10; do you want 2 or 3 be returned for user B?

Comment: good question. 2, realistically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a way to achieve this with the Arel interface, but you can do something like this (assuming your user is loaded into `@user`)

```
idx = nil
Payment.order("value desc").each_with_index do |payment, index|
  if payment.user_id == @user.id
    idx = index
    break
  end
end
```

While you could query for all payment records less than the amount `@user` paid to get a number, it won't account for records that paid the same amount, as you will not know which comes first for users that paid the same.

Comment: would this not be hugely inefficient? I'm thinking this is doable without calling all of the payments?

Comment: Potentially, yes. Depends on the size of your database. I do like the idea of getting the number of records that paid less than your current user, but that could also work against you if the user paid $100, which might be high, and theres +100 users that paid less. Maybe the solution is that of the two egg problem, or a binary search even: http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/july22012/index.html